# Failed to read the same file using multithread

Tags: c++, multithreading, io, fopen, fread

I created 50 threads to read the same file at the same time and then, in each thread, tried to write its content to new file that create with different name.
The code was supposed to generate 50 different files.
But I got unexpected results that it just generate 3~5 files.
[image: Results after running my code]

When all the read the same file, there is no race-condition, and each thread is aimed to write its content to different file.

Can somebody help me? Thank you!

My code is listed below and it is a modification from [Reference](https://github.com/arturmkrtchyan/zero-copy/blob/master/fcopy.c)

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

void copy(const char *src_path, const char *dst_path);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::vector<std::thread> vth;
    char *tmp = "Copy.deb";
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
    {
        char src[40];
        memset(src, '\0', sizeof(src));
        sprintf(src, "%d", i);
        strcat(src, tmp);
        vth.emplace_back(std::bind(copy, "Original.deb", strdup(src)));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
    {
        vth[i].join();
    }

    return 0;
}

void copy(const char *src_path, const char *dst_path)
{
    FILE *src, *dst;
    int buffer_size = 8 * 1024;
    char buffer[buffer_size];
    size_t length;

    src = fopen(src_path, "rb");
    dst = fopen(dst_path, "wb");

    while (!feof(src))
    {
        length = fread(buffer, 1, buffer_size, src);
        fwrite(buffer, 1, length, dst);
    }

    fclose(src);
    fclose(dst);
}
```

Comment: The recommended number of threads is the number of cores multiplied by two, plus one. 50 threads might as well be *slower* than a single-threaded application, not only because CPU core starvation but also because of I/O starvation.

Comment: This code is not C:(

Comment: But you have a much worse problem, that leads your code to have *undefined behavior*: You pass a pointer to the local array `src` to all threads. This array will go out of bounds and cease to exist each iteration of the loop! The pointer might become invalid at any moment in your thread.

Comment: Please adjust your tags, your code looks like `c++`, not `c`.

Comment: Furthermore, please read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) And if you decide to use C++ streams instead (which you really should) [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: Finally, [here's a list of good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282). Please invest in a couple and learn C++ properly. Or take a couple of classes.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, The number of CPU cores is relevant when CPU cores are the bottleneck. In this program (assuming the mistake called out by Jeremy Friesner is fixed), I/O almost certainly will be the bottleneck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you are passing `src` (which is a pointer to a local variable on your main thread's stack) to your thread's entry function, but since your `copy()` function runs asynchronously in a separate thread, the `char src[40]` array that you are passing a pointer to has already been been popped off of the main thread's stack (and likely overwritten by other data) before the `copy()` function gets a chance to read its contents.

The easy fix would be to make a copy of the string on the heap, so that you can guarantee the string will remain valid until the the `copy()` function executes and reads it:

```
    vth.emplace_back(std::bind(copy, "Original.deb", strdup(src)));
```

... and be sure to have your `copy()` function free the heap-allocation when it's done using it:

```
void copy(const char *src_path, const char *dst_path)
{
  FILE *src, *dst;
  int buffer_size = 8 * 1024;
  char buffer[buffer_size];
  size_t length;

  src = fopen(src_path, "rb");
  dst = fopen(dst_path, "wb");

  free(dst_path);   // free the string previously allocated by strdup()

  [...]
```

Note that you don't currently have the same problem with the "Original.deb" argument since "Original.deb" is a string-literal and therefore stored statically in the executable, which means it remains valid for as long as the program is running -- but if/when you change your code to not use a string-literal for that argument, you'd likely need to do something similar for it as well.